# Android: How to expand and shrink a view diagonally?

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to animate a view which expands and shrinks back to the initial size. I tried using animation set to add two animations so that the second animation will start after the first animation but was not able to get it working.

```
AnimationSet expandAndShrink = new AnimationSet(true);
ScaleAnimation expand = new ScaleAnimation(
     1f, 1.5f, 
     1f, 1.5f,
     Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,
     Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);

ScaleAnimation shrink = new ScaleAnimation(
     1.5f, 1f, 
     1.5f, 1f,
     Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1f,
     Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1f);

expandAndShrink.addAnimation(expand);
expandAndShrink.addAnimation(shrink)
expandAndShrink.setFillAfter(true);
expandAndShrink.setDuration(1000);
expandAndShrink.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));

view.bringToFront();
view.startAnimation(expandAndShrink);
```

I really appreciate any help to get it working. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have fixed "expand" and "shrink" animations, and added durations for both. Also you should add shrink.setStartOffset(1000); so second animation starts later

```
    AnimationSet expandAndShrink = new AnimationSet(true);
    ScaleAnimation expand = new ScaleAnimation(
         1f, 1.5f, 
         1f, 1.5f,
         Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,
         Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
    expand.setDuration(1000);

    ScaleAnimation shrink = new ScaleAnimation(
         1.5f, 1f, 
         1.5f, 1f,
         Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f,
         Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f);
    shrink.setStartOffset(1000);
    shrink.setDuration(1000);

    expandAndShrink.addAnimation(expand);
    expandAndShrink.addAnimation(shrink);
    expandAndShrink.setFillAfter(true);
    expandAndShrink.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));

    view.startAnimation(expandAndShrink);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain the way I chose to animate layout changes.

Android has a special Animation class named `ScaleAnimation` where we can smoothly expand or collapse views.

Show view by expanding diagonally:

```
ScaleAnimation expanding = new ScaleAnimation(
   0, 1.0f,
   0, 1.0f,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
expanding.setDuration(250);

view.startAnimation(expanding)
```

where the constructor used is:

```
ScaleAnimation(float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY, int pivotXType, float pivotXValue, int pivotYType, float pivotYValue)
```

So you can change values accordingly.

For example, the below example would animate view horizontally:

```
ScaleAnimation expanding = new ScaleAnimation(
   0, 1.1f,
   1f, 1f,
   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,
   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
expanding.setDuration(250);
```

You can change `fromX`,`toX`, `fromY` & `toY` according to the need.

For example if view is shown and you have to just expand it, put `fromX` and `fromY` to `1.0f`, and `toX`, `toY` according to the need.

Now, using the same class you can create a more cool effect for showing view by expanding view a little bit extra and then shrinking it to original size. For this purpose, `AnimationSet` will be used. So it would create a kind of bubble effect.

Below example is for creating bubble effect for showing the view:

```
AnimationSet expandThenShrink = new AnimationSet(true);

ScaleAnimation expanding = new ScaleAnimation(
   0, 1.1f,
   0, 1.1f,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
expanding.setDuration(250);

ScaleAnimation shrinking = new ScaleAnimation(
   1.1f, 1f,
   1.1f, 1f,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
shrinking.setStartOffset(250);
shrinking.setDuration(120);

expandThenShrink.addAnimation(expanding);
expandThenShrink.addAnimation(shrinking);
expandThenShrink.setFillAfter(true);
expandThenShrink.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));

view.startAnimation(expandThenShrink);
```