# How to make a shrink and expand animation in android

Tags: android

Im new to animation coding in Android. Can anyone please help me in doing the following animation.

1. On click of a button, a Linearlayout should be shrinked in vertical direction, in otherwords LinearLayout should be hidden in Vertical direction.
2. On click of another button, the same layout should be visible in opposite direction

Also this should support on Android 2.2 and above.

Can anyone please tell how can I do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done any code so far? If no, read this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315154/android-how-to-expand-and-shrink-a-view-diagonally

Comment: Take a look at here: developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html. After learning a bit of the basics of animation in Android, you can achieve what you are looking for by scaling.

Comment: @Marek, I had checked the link and used the following piece of code, but the view just closes without any animation.        ScaleAnimation shrink = new ScaleAnimation(
                0f, 0f,
                1f, 0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f);
        shrink.setDuration(5000);
        shrink.setFillAfter(true);
        shrink.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));

Comment: Have you set shrink.setStartOffset and shirnt.setDuration? Feel free to ask if you have any further problems, also you can vote if my post was helpful.